# When can I be sure that if the == operator evaluates to true for integral operands of different types then the operands are really equal?

Tags: c++, integer

I know that integral conversions can be really tricky and applying operands of different integral types can break for example the `<` operator:

```
std::cout << (-1 < 1u)
false
```

Or even the `==` operator:

```
std::cout << (4294967295u == -1)
true
```

(although, granted, both of the above examples generate a warning)

What I would like to know is:

- If I compare two operands with the `==` operator, and the value of either operand lies within the range of the other operand, can I be sure that if the statement evaluates to `true` the values are really equal?
- If not, under what exactly circumstances does the `==` operator produce reasonable results? How to use it to compare signed and unsigned values without errors?

Comment: As long as at least one of the operands is unsigned, make sure none of the values are negative. Then you should generally get what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

> - If I compare two operands with the `==` operator, and the value of either operand lies within the range of the other operand, can I be sure that if the statement evaluates to `true` the values are really equal?

**Yes**.  As long as two conditions are met:

1. both arguments are integral, and
2. both argument types are either of the same signedness, or the signed value happens to be non-negative.

**But:** This does not mean that this is a good idea.  The compiler warning should not be taken lightly.

For most binary operators (including `==`) and integer operands, the compiler will first apply *integral promotions* (C++11: §4.5[conv.prom]) to each operand independently.  This converts operands to at least `unsigned int` or (preferrably) `int`.  This preserves all possibly values of the operands, but it can change one type from an unsigned one to a larger signed one.

Next, the compiler looks for a common type (C++11: §5[expr]/9).  This type will be no larger than the larger of the two operands.  Here indeed values can be altered: it can happen that a signed type is converted to an unsigned type, and in that case negative values won't carry over.  But since we have excluded negative values, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Always in similar case when you compare between unsigned and signed number 
the operation will be between 2 unsigned number.

in this case

```
(-1 < 1u) 
-1 = 0b11111111111111111111111  (1* 32 times)=4294967295u 
1u = 0b00000000000000000000001
```

so its very clear that this is false because

```
4294967295u = 0b11111111111111111111111
```

you cant  represent  4294967295 not in unsigned int.

and you can see that

```
-1==4294967295u
```

in general the some compilers will give you warning in this case but you have to be careful..